# When using xp_cmdshell to run some curl command in Stored Procedure is slow, why is that?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, xp-cmdshell

This is my code:

```
SET @GETCommand = 'curl --silent -X GET -u user:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://jira.com/rest/api/latest/.... > "C:\Test.txt"' 

EXEC xp_cmdshell @GETCommand
```

When running it outside of Stored Procedure (SP), it takes 2 seconds, however when running it in SP it can take up to 2-3 minutes, why is that?

Please note that I must use variable (@GETCommand) since I've dynamic variables in the SET @GETCommand

Comment: Did you try running cmdshell on the same account that SQL Server uses outside SP? Second try writing file to different location instead of drive C. There is popup window when you try to directly save anything on C drive. It may be default timeout.

Comment: I grant SQL account user Write access to all C:\ and storing the file in different drive, however I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Additional notes is that when I run the command through SQL but not in stored procedure then it takes 2 sec. The problem exist only in the SP.

Comment: Please post **entire stored procedure**. Probably something else took  that time, like building stirng to execute not actual xp_cmdshell call

Answer (score 0):

Using `xp_cmdshell` is not safe and it could be a **security issue**. When you want to ***access*** to ***resources out of SQL Server*** for example, `xp_cmdshell`, SQL Server does not have any control over any issues occurred. So I strongly suggest you change the solution and create another service or app to do your task, instead, it is **the only solution** to do your task.